# Can't connect to Ubuntu MongoDB instance from MongoChef Client

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, firewall

All, new to MongoDB and new to Ubuntu.  I have an Ubuntu VPS with MongoDB running.  On my local machine, I'm trying to set-up MongoChef for my admin GUI.  It creates the SSH tunnel successfully but then fails when connecting to my VPS on port 27017.  I assumed it was a firewall on my VPS blocking traffic but using the ufw status command, I see the port is accepting traffic:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
```

Any ideas of what I can try next?  I've also commented out the blockip line in my mongodb config file since that seems to have resolved the issue for others.

[MongoChef Connection Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LikW6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SirOn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my mongodb was not restarting properly after commenting the bind_ip.  Had to work through multiple repair commands, start the service again, and issuing a netstat -a | grep "LISTEN " shows that port 27017 was now open to accept from any IP.  MongoChef connected after that.